# How do I find my own questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to edit my previous question(s). How?

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?

> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Please tell me HOW....

Comment: Apparently you have 20 questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/344494/anne?tab=questions&sort=newest

Comment: Click on your name ....==> https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/344494/anne

Comment: Just being curious : Is it me ? you ? your system ? inverting lower and upper cases ?

Comment: @anne this question sounds like your loosing your mind, q8ustion, is this your real troubles or is something other/different that has higher priority? no disrespect

Answer (score 2):

A (generic) link to your main account's questions is: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=questions (adapted from [Glorfindel's "/users/current" answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332251/307535)). There should be a link at the bottom of that page that would show you any of your deleted questions.

More specifically, your links would be:

- Your current questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/344494/anne?tab=questions
- Your deleted questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/344494